# Select Entity with condition on node id

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to select an Entity with a condition on the node id.
Here's the query I use:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
    ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
    ->fieldCondition('nid', 'value', $id, '=')
    ->range($page, 1);
$result = $query->execute();
```

I get the following error:

> EntityFieldQueryException: Unknown field: nid in EntityFieldQuery->addFieldCondition()

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For EFQ, you need to filter on the entity condition column `entity_id` which is the node id.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('entity_id', $id)
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'event')
    ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
    ->range($page, 1);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel bad for not noticing that I was applying the filter to the fields and not the entity... I should get some rest. Thanks!